# Getting smallest value from column that holds numbers as strings

Tags: mysql, casting

I'm saving numbers as strings because they are generally larger than the maximum limits MySQL allows for integers.

What I'm trying to get is the smallest and largest values from this column, but just comparing as strings returns very different results.

I've tried to add a CONVERT clause to my query like so:

```
"SELECT end_timestamp FROM ".$db_table_prefix."user_events ORDER BY CONVERT('end_timestamp', SIGNED INTEGER) DESC LIMIT 1"
```

But the result coming through is not correct. I think the CONVERT clause is not converting to integers in the way I was expecting it to.

So what is the best way to convert strings to integers and get the smallest value?

Comment: The best way is to store numbers as numbers. Besides `INT`, there is `BIGINT` where you can store any integer value from `-(2^63)` up to `(2^63)-1`. There is also the `DECIMAL` datatype that allows even larger values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a MySQL instance to test on, but it looks like a workaround may solve your problem. I don't know that the issue here is the numbers are too large for conversion, but if they can't be integers in the database, why should it be possible to convert them to integers outside the database?

Try something like this:

```
"SELECT end_timestamp FROM ".$db_table_prefix."user_events ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(end_timestamp) DESC, end_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"
```

That will sort by the number of characters first, which is where string sorts on numbers fall apart (as long as you don't have any leading zeros), followed by a numerical sort on numbers which are the same length. If that still doesn't work you may need to `SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(end_timestamp) AS ts_len' to calculate the value outside of the sort command. That is where I really don't know which will work because I don't have a MySQL instance available to test on.

You also may want to consider a data type more suited to timestamps, like `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME`, which could likely be converted to the format you need once they're outside the database.

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked well for me to get the largest value. I'm working with it to get the smallest one now. Unfortunately I've had to bypass timestamp/datetime types because timestamps are restricted to UNIX epoch (I need my timestamps to start from 0000-00-00 00:00:00) and datetime will only go back as far as 1000-01-01... On a 32Bit system int's won't cut it unfortunately. Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number as a string and it is an integer with no leading 0s, you can compare it by comparing the length first and then the value.  For instance, the following will order by `col1` correctly (assuming the above):

```
select t.*
from t
order by char_length(col1), col1;
```

So, one way to get the minimum is:

```
select col1
from t
order by char_length(col1), col1
limit 1;
```

You can also get both in a `group by` by doing:

```
select substring_index(group_concat(col1 order by char_length(col1), col1), ',', 1
                      ) as mincol1,
       substring_index(group_concat(col1 order by char_length(col1) desc, col1 desc), ',', 1
                      ) as maxcol1
from t;
```

If you have zeros in front of the numbers and or decimal places, the ideas are the same, but the coding is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Many thanks for this, it appears to be the same method as the one I accepted, although it didn't seem to work for me.